# how to detect orentation in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I am trying to detect orientation in ios using ionic .I do the following thing

- create blank project
- Add platform .Then add this plugin http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/deviceOrientation/
- Insert ngcordova.js file.

  ```
      <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
      <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
      -->

      <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
      <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

      <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
      <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>

      <!-- your app's js -->
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="starter" class="platform-ios platform-cordova platform-webview">
         <div ng-controller="ThisCtrl">
      <ion-view>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
          <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
            <button ng-click="startCompass()" style="position: absolute;top: 90px">stsrt</button>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
         </div>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```

**JS code**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})// Ionic Starter App


    angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

    .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if(window.StatusBar) {
          StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
      });
    }).controller('ThisCtrl', function($scope,$cordovaDeviceOrientation) {
            $scope.startCompass = function() {
                var options = {
                    frequency: 500
                };

                $scope.watchPromise = $cordovaDeviceOrientation.watchHeading(options);

                $scope.watchPromise.then(
                    null,
                    function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    },
                    function(result) {
                        alert("--")
                        $scope.dir = result.trueHeading;
                    }
                );

            };

            $scope.stopCompass = function() {
                $cordovaDeviceOrientation.clearWatch($scope.watchPromise.watchID);
            };
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

I unlocked orientation in an ionic project for the first time myself today.  I ended up using this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation and all that i needed to do was add this js.

```
screen.unlockOrientation();
```

If all you want to do is unlock orientation in your ionic project, and you don't really need access to the compass, this might be a really convenient option for you to use instead.

Comment: The ng-cordova plugin uses the word "orientation" to mean compass heading.  That appears to be the measurement that Pallavi is after (I'm having the same problem).  The plugin you reccomend deals with screen orientation (vertical or horizontal).